# php query_posts orderby=random causing css to break

Tags: php, css, wordpress, random, sql-order-by

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=rand') ?>
```

Hey all,

I've tried to implement the above piece of code into my portfolio page template.php. 
http://www.some-things.net/category/work/

It's causing the css to break every so often. Reload it until it breaks and you will see what I mean. It pushes 2 of the *portfolioitem* blocks to the right a touch and forces the third to drop a line?

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class="gallery">
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=rand') ?>           
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="portfolioItem">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="desctitle" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <span class="desctitle"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</span>                     

                    </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: It looks like it happens quite often.  On most page loads, I see a random row get messed up on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error isn't in the random layout code.  It's caused by an empty "tile" in your page.  here's the source of the offending tile:

```
<div class="portfolioItem">
    <a href="http://www.some-things.net/work/love-jungle/" class="desctitle" title="Love Jungle"><span class="desctitle">Love Jungle</span></a>
</div>
```

Notice there's no image.

Comment: Very nice Saurav! 
I didn't realize. It turns out that I had not set a thumbnail image for that post yet! (I'd completely forgotten about the post actually). Thanks for your help!